# Drop lined shadow on button text

Tags: html, css

I want to drop lined shadow on a link or button. Kind of flat style. You can see this implemented already here

```css
a.button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
}

a.button:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

a.button:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 3px solid red;
  right: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
}

a.button:hover:after {
  background-color: green;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Click Here</a>
```

But the problem is that the box and the shadow are overlapping on the button text so the button text is not visible. Is there any way to fix that? I don't want to add any extra html tags like span into this as the links are going to be auto generated using Wordpress. So that is why I have used before-after pseudo css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set :after z-index to -1. to send it backward futher

```
a.button:after {
    z-index: -1;
}
```